# export excel in mvc displaying in the browser instead of downloading the file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to export my webgrid data in excel format, but its writing the content in the browser instead of downloading it. Here is my code i have referred many examples everyone telling like the same, but none of them working. Here is my code

```
var northwind = Database.Open("Northwind");
    var sql = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, Country, Phone FROM Customers";
    var customers = northwind.Query(sql);

    var connString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                    Data Source={0}/{1};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'", 
                                    appData, newFileName);
    var provider = "System.Data.OleDb";

    using (var excel = Database.OpenConnectionString(connString, provider)){

        sql = @"INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, Country, Phone) 
            VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6)";
        foreach(var customer in customers){
            excel.Execute(sql,  
                customer.CustomerID, 
                customer.CompanyName, 
                customer.ContactName, 
                customer.Address, 
                customer.City, 
                customer.Country, 
                customer.Phone);
        }
    }

    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.TransmitFile(newFile);
    Response.Flush();
    File.Delete(newFile);
    Response.End();
```

and my view is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#excel').appendTo($('tfoot tr td')).on('hover', function () {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });
            $('#excel').on('click', function () {
                $('<iframe src="/GenerateExcel"></iframe>').appendTo('body').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>


@{
    Page.Title = "Export To Excel";
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    var query = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, Country, Phone FROM Customers";
    var data = db.Query(query);
    var grid = new WebGrid(data, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
}

    <h1>Export to Excel</h1>
    <div id="gridContainer">
        <div id="grid">
            @grid.GetHtml(    
                tableStyle : "table",
                alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
                headerStyle : "header",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("CustomerID", "ID"),
                    grid.Column("CompanyName", "Company Name"),
                    grid.Column("ContactName", "Contact Name"),
                    grid.Column("Address"),
                    grid.Column("City"),
                    grid.Column("Country"),
                    grid.Column("Phone")
                )
            )
            <img src="/images/excel-icon.png" id="excel" alt="Export to Excel" title="Export to Excel" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above code i found in the below site and try to reproduce the same, but writing the content in the browser instead of downloading. Here is the source

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/207/Exporting-The-Razor-WebGrid-To-Excel-Using-OleDb
Any help please?

Comment: do you have any MIME type defined in configuration or in IIS with name "application/octet-stream", if yes then remove.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code for this purpose.

```
  Response.Clear();
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=download.xlsx");
  Response.Charset = "";
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  content.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream); //content is the file stream
  Response.End();
```

So instead of using the *TransmitFile* method try to use the *Response.OutputStream*.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your `Response.ContentType` to

```
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
```